# Javascript Hash Object Not Updating Values Properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hash

I am having some trouble getting my hash to properly hold the value I am looking for.

Some background to clarify the values here.

I am creating an exercise app in React. The last feature is to create a search function to return a users maximum lift.

The test is for bench press. The values are going in as follows.

405 
435
285
225
135 
185

No matter how I structure the hash, it returns {Bench Press: 185}, I want it to sort through the data and only change the value if the new value is greater than the old.

```
const completedExercises = {};

    mergedSets.forEach(set => {
      if (set) {
        let exercise = exercises[set.exercise_id]
        let name = exercise.exercise_name

        if (exercise.ex_type === 'lift') {
          if (completedExercises[name] < (set.weight_lifted)) {
            completedExercises[name] = set.weight_lifted
          } else {
            completedExercises[name] = set.weight_lifted
          }
        }
      }
    })
```

The first conditional is checking if set is in case the user has no workouts stored in their log.

The second is only taking exercises with the type lift, since cardio exercises don't have a weight lifted value.

I can see in my debugger those two if conditionals working properly and all the data going through.

I have a hash of exercises, a set has an exercise_id, which is where I am getting the name. The set stores the weight lifted.

I am rather new to JS, so I am not sure if this has to do with using forEach, in the meantime I am going to try a for loop. Any help would be appreciated. No matter the order, this is always setting the hash equal to the last value past into it.

Comment: Why do the inner `if` and `else` branches do the same thing as each other?

Comment: And the result is the same refactored into a for loop.

Comment: i believe what you really need is to flip the less that sign and as @nnnnnn mentioned your if and else statements are doing the same thing

Comment: Javascript (ECMAScript) doesn't have "Hash Objects", it has Objects. You should supply example input and output, what is the value of *exercises*?

Comment: @AmrAly facepalm....easy fix, the else conditional was setting the value regardless of the condition I wanted...easy fix, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The for loop or forEach didn't matter, it was my else conditional as pointed out in the comments! Thanks for the help, late night, and a long day...

```
 const completedExercises = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < mergedSets.length; i++) {
      let set = mergedSets[i];
      let exercise = exercises[set.exercise_id]
      let name = exercise.exercise_name

      if (exercise.ex_type === 'lift') {
        if (completedExercises[name] < (set.weight_lifted)) {
          completedExercises[name] = set.weight_lifted
        } else if (!completedExercises[name]) {
          completedExercises[name] = set.weight_lifted
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Be careful with `!completedExercises[name]`. In a case where *set.weight_lifted* can be negative and *completedExercises[name]* can be zero, this may replace zero with a negative value when that should not occur. But it's probably OK in this case.

Comment: @RobG thank you, I am rather new to JS, is there a better conditional?

Comment: The safest test in this case is `if (!completedExercises.hasOwnProperty(name))` but if you create *completedExercises* with no inherited properties using `completedExercises = Object.create(null)` you can also safely do `if (!(name in completedExercises))`. I hope the code formats OK.

Comment: You can refactor the tests a little and do `if (name in completedExercises) { /* do less than test & assignment */} else { /*assign to comletedExercises[name] */}`.